# Error when refering to TRUE/FALSE value for IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I keep getting the same error. Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8) Refer to a line with value either True or False. I tried also to work with 1 and 0 instead of True or False but it's still not working.

```
    Sub AddNonStockIncomings()

Dim Row_Pos As Long
Dim ABJ_Val_Col As Integer
Dim JOS_Val_Col As Integer
Dim MIU_Val_Col As Integer
Dim YOL_Val_Col As Integer
Dim Tot_count_OT_OP As Integer
Dim Tot_count_INV As Integer


Item_Code_Col = 1  'OT OP Pivot
ABJ_Val_Col = 2 'OT OP Pivot
JOS_Val_Col = 3 'OT OP Pivot
MIU_Val_Col = 4 'OT OP Pivot
YOL_Val_Col = 5 'OT OP Pivot
Row_Pos = 3 'OT OP Pivot
I = 1
Tot_count_INV = Worksheets(3).Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Count + 3
Tot_count_OT_OP = Worksheets(4).Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Count



'MsgBox (Tot_count_INV)
'MsgBox (Tot_count_OT_OP)

Do While Row_Pos >= Tot_count

**If Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value = True Then**

Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, Item_Code_Col).Copy Worksheets(5).Cells(Tot_count_OT_OP, 1)
End If

Row_Pos = Row_Pos + 1

Loop


'Add the reset of values
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What does the cell actually contain? Is it some string containing "True" or "False"?

Comment: You appear to be in danger of going off the sheet and get object defined error with your loop when Row_Pos exceeds the number of available rows in the sheet. Are you sure your logic is correct for loop termination? What is the value of Row_Pos when the error occurs?

Comment: What is the value of `Row_Pos` when it blows? What is actually in `Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value` when it blows? Also, _please_ for us _and_ for you, be consistent with your indentation!

Comment: Additionally: You should put `Option Explicit` at the top of **all** your code modules. You `Do While Row_Pos >= Tot_count`, but nowhere in this code do you declare or assign `Tot_count`. Without `Option Explicit` a new variable is declared on the spot with a value of 0 and your loop will continue until your worksheet runs out of rows as @QHarr mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Force a boolean result.

```
If cbool(Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value) Then
```

For all intents and purposes, a boolean False is zero. By strict definition, anything that is not False is True. When used mathematically or numerically compared, False is zero (0) in the worksheet or VBA but True is one (1) on the worksheet and minus one (-1) in VBA.

You don't need to compare a boolean to True or False. That is like asking `If True = True then it is True`. You can simply use the criteria directly; e.g. `If Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value Then`.

You should not use positive or negative integers directly as True/False booleans. Wrap each in a CBool conversion wrapper. This is particularly important when stacking conditions with the And operator. VBA's And operator is bitwise so while (2 and 3) is True, (2 And 4) is False.

Comment: Some specification: If Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value Then. The -> Cells (Row_Pos, 8), the number 8 refer to column with booleans value TRUE and FALSE (not TRUE/FALSE strings).

Comment: In that case, `If Worksheets(4).Cells(Row_Pos, 8).Value Then` is sufficient.